# Pipe Characters in Ruby Code

Tags: ruby

I'm following an ebook, and this:

```
def titled_name
  @honorific ||= 'Esteemed'
  titled_name = "#{@honorific} #{@name}"
end
```

is throwing an error:

```
SyntaxError: lib/example.rb:25: syntax error, unexpected tOP_ASGN @honorific | |= Esteemed'
```

From the example code in the ebook, it looks like one of the pipe characters is a little more bold than the other, but that just might be an odd issue in the book. Can you see what is wrong with this? Are they just the two regular pipe characters?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
@honorific | |= "Esteemed"
```

You mistyped the code. There should not be a space between the pipes (these vertical lines are called pipes)

```
@honorific ||= "Esteemed"
```

Also, no programming language (that I know of) makes use of rich formatting (bold characters vs normal ones). That is certainly a defect in the print.

Comment: Yes, that did it. Thank you! The example in the book also looked to have a space.

Comment: PLASMA and Fortress are at least two languages that use formatting.

Comment: I glanced through the [introduction to plasma](http://www.kivadesigngroupe.com/Kiva%20Professional/ProfessionalMaterial/Software/Plasma/Plasma_MTV_2005_paper.pdf) paper and didn't find trace of it. @JörgWMittag: could you post a quote?

Comment: I'm talking about the PLASMA by Carl Hewitt, the language that he used to introduce the Actor Model. I think the *actual* MacLisp implementation was different, but the original language specification used formatting. Oh, another one: colorFORTH, as the name implies, uses color for distinguishing definitions from calls. Also, the original APL (before it was implemented) used two-dimensional layout.

Comment: Interesting, thanks. Turns out, using formatting is bad if you want to be popular. Where are all those languages now? :)

Answer (score 0):

I am pretty new to Ruby too, but there are basically 2 reasons to use the pipes that I have come across.

1) || is "or". It is used to evaluate whether *either* or 2 arguments is true, and returns true if yes.

2) || is also used to create a variable within a block.